# Trigger Error using MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, intervals

this is the first time I try to set a trigger, but really, I've been working on it for 1hour trying my best, but I failed hard my attempts.

The code is this, way very simple, I declare a forum-post table, and I want to set the expiration date with triggers.
    `CREATE TABLE post(
      pid INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      owner_id INT,
      title VARCHAR(140),
      text VARCHAR(255),
      posted TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
      expiration DATETIME,
      PRIMARY KEY( pid ),
      FOREIGN KEY( owner_id ) REFERENCES user( userid )
     );
     delimiter $$
     CREATE TRIGGER post
      BEFORE INSERT post
      FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
       SET new.'expiration' = DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 60 DAY);
      END;
     $$
     DELIMITER;`

Can you please explain me where's the error in the trigger declaration?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: This is the error I get:
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'post
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
   SET new.'expiration' = DATE_ADD(NOW(), IN' at line 2

Comment: You missed only a space: The last line's got to be `DELIMITER ;`

Comment: @VMai: I tried to add a space, but I get the same error..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were only several minor issues:

- the ON keyword was missing on `BEFORE INSERT ON post`
- there were single quotes around the column name `new.expiration` instead of backticks or better no quotes
- the blank between DELIMITER and the delimiter string is needed too.

It should be

```
 delimiter $$
 CREATE TRIGGER post
     BEFORE INSERT ON post    -- ON missing
     FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
         SET new.expiration = DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 60 DAY);  -- no single quotes
     END;
 $$
 DELIMITER ;  -- blank needed
```

instead. Some other pair of eyes come in useful in such cases.